# Best way to simulate virtual networks

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v-server-2012

I'm wanting to have a vitual test network on either hyper-v or ESXI ( I Don't care which one)

I want to have a multi network virtual environment.  Lets say three networks: 192.168.1.0, 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0.

I want to use the networks to simulate a multi domain or multi site domain.

Whats the best way of doing this.  I have VMware workstation but it won't create more then one NAT virtual network.

So how would I go about doing this in either Hyper-v 2012 or ESXI?

Comment: With the Virtual Network Editor in VMware Workstation you can create a bunch of custom host-only networks.  Your question about ESXi/Hyper-V is really too broad to answer.  If you want to go with one of those then install them and start setting it up, return here if you have a specific question.

Comment: If I go into the virtual editor then I can create more networks but it wants me to connect each new network to a separate physical network adapter.  So do I need to put multiple network adapters into the computer so I can create more then one "usable" network?  Am I understanding this right?

Comment: When I create select Add Network it just creates a host-only network for me automatically.  Not sure why it's asking you to add a physical adapter.  Which Workstation version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be to create all Host Only networks, and then get a linux router distro (best imho Vyatta) and create a VM multihomed with all the networks that acts as router between the host only networks, and can even NAT to your bridged network.